# Flutter: How to setup Stream to auto log in into app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make a Flutter app with Anonymous Sign In with Firebase. I want to setup Stream (or any other method) so that once after getting Signed In and upon restarting the app it doesn't go to again Sign in page instead it should go to Home page.

I'm following this tutorial. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state

I looked into many answers here which revolved around something about Provider and all. As a beginner it went above my head.

I'm providing my codes here:

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Wrapper(),
    );
  }
}
```

***wrapper.dart***

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((User user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('the user is currently signed out');
        return Authenticate();
      } else {
        print('The User is currently signed In');
        return Home();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**the authservice file**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //sign in anonympusly
  Future signinanon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User userdetails = result.user;
      return userdetails;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve proper streaming?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need for Stream when you can do it very easily this way:

```
 checkIfLoggedIn() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      // logged
      return Home();
    }
  }
```

then call it in **home** in **main.dart**
Hope this works!

Comment: I was asking about Streams and Provider because like if I login through app it should directly take me to Home() and if I logout on Home() then it should directly take me to LogIn page. For this reason I think Stream and Provider will be important. How to implement all of these?

Answer (score 0):

main.dart:

```
return MaterialApp(
     home: FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
            future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot){
                       if (snapshot.hasData){
                           FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data; // this is your user instance
                           /// is because there is user already logged
                           return MainScreen();
                        }
                         /// other way there is no user logged.
                         return LoginScreen();
             }
         )
          );
```

Comment: I was asking about Streams and Provider because like if I login through app it should directly take me to Home() and if I logout on Home() then it should directly take me to LogIn page. For this reason I think Stream and Provider will be important. How to implement all of these?

Comment: `SharedPrefereces` can identify you as authenticated locally. `Firebase` automatically manages the preference without that. These are the most commonly used services. How do you authenticate with stream and provider? Why is it important for you??

Comment: I want to do the same as shown in in this repo [link](https://github.com/iamshaunjp/flutter-firebase/tree/lesson-9/). I don't have to authenticate with Stream and Provider. I just want to use that to manage states. firebase_auth will take care of authentication